# The set of points in the sample space $\Omega$ which belong to exactly $k$ of the $A_i$ in $F$ ,belongs to $F$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $A_1,A_2,...,A_m \in F$ and $k$ is a positive integer, show that the set of points in $\Omega$ which belong to exactly $k$ of the $A_i$ belongs to $F$

---

I have proven this with $m=2 $ and $k=1$, namely the case of the symmetric difference. But I don't know how to proceed in a rigorous way.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mathcal{I}_k$ denote the set of $k$-combinations from $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$. Then the required set can be written as
$$
\bigcup_{I\in \mathcal{I_k}}\left(\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i \cap \bigcap_{j\notin I} A_j^c\right)\in \mathcal{F}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $M=\{1,\dots,m\}$ and let $I\subseteq M$ with $|I|=k$. The set of $\omega \in \Omega$ with  $\omega\in A_i$ if $i\in I$ and $\omega \notin A_j$ for $j\notin I$ can be written as
$$\Big(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\Big)\setminus\Big(\bigcup_{j\in M \setminus I} A_j\Big).$$
To consider all combinations with exactly $k$ of the $A_i$ we can write
$$\bigcup_{I\subseteq M \\ |I|=k}\Big[\Big(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\Big)\setminus\Big(\bigcup_{j\in M \setminus I} A_j\Big)\Big],$$
and we have thus written the set as a finite union of sets belonging to $F$.

Answer (score 2):

$f:=\sum_{i=1}^m\mathbf1_{A_i}$ is - as a finite sum of measurable functions - a measurable function.

Consequently $\{f=k\}$ is a measurable set.

The answers of d.k.o. and Leander are more fundamental though.